# Insert and Get operations on JSON object in MongoDB with Spring Boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

How can I save JSON object with different level of hierarchies in MongoDB ?

For example :-JSON

{
    "name": "abc",
    "password": "xyz",
    "address": {
        "street": "ghgjk",
        "pin": 25646
    },
    "readingHabbits": [
        "jkjsdj",
        "sdkhks",
        "jlcsd"
    ],
    "eatingHabbits": {
        "internalObjOne": {
            "dkks": "jdskdfl",
            "lfld": "hfslvlsk"
        },
        "internalObjectSecond": {
            "cjdlksl": "hcdkjnjkcs",
            "cjsdjljsl": "chsdskjc"
        }
    }
}

How can I store above JSON values into MongoDB in different Collections using SpringBoot and Java?

Also how can I get the same result when I do repository.findAll();

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```
db.getCollection("images").insertOne(
        new Document("name", "abc")
        .append("password", "xyz")
        .append("address",
                new Document()
                .append("street", "ghgjk")
                .append("pin", 25646))
        .append("readingHabbits", Arrays.asList("jkjsdj", "sdkhks", "jlcsd"))
        .append("eatingHabbits", Arrays.asList(
                new Document()
                .append("internalObjOne",
                        new Document()
                        .append("dkks", "jdskdfl")
                        .append("lfld", "hfslvlsk")),
                new Document()
                .append("internalObjectSecond",
                new Document()
                        .append("cjdlksl", "hcdkjnjkcs")
                        .append("cjsdjljsl", "chsdskjc"))
        )
)
);
```

Comment: Can't we do it with some annotation at entity level like @DBRef or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
thanks for the answer, But I think I didn't made myself clear.
Suppose I have a json object.
{ "name": "abc", "password": "xyz", "address": { "street": "ghgjk", "pin": 25646 }, "readingHabbits": [ "jkjsdj", "sdkhks", "jlcsd" ], "eatingHabbits": { "internalObjOne": { "dkks": "jdskdfl", "lfld": "hfslvlsk" }, "internalObjectSecond": { "cjdlksl": "hcdkjnjkcs", "cjsdjljsl": "chsdskjc" } } }

Base class :-

@Document(collection="user")
public class User{
@Id
private String id;
private String name;
private String password;
@DBRef
private Address address;
@DBRef
private ReadingHabbits readingHabbits;
//setter and getter 
}

@Document(collection="address")
public class Address{
@Id
private String id;
private String street;
private int pin;
//setter and getter 
}

Do we need to create separate classes for "ReadingHabbits" and "EatingHabbits" ?

If not then is the above approach correct to map two different entities with DBRef and save it to two different collection in MongoDB?

Or do we have any other way to do the same operation ?


----------
```